# How to add multiple values to one field of a model in Asp.Net Core Web App?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, razor-pages

I want to allow the user to add as many image URL's as they want.

So I made a class in Asp.Net Core razor pages Web App. Here is my current Code:

```
public class Post
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public List<string> Url { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to create the actual razor pages using scafolding and selecting this model as the model of the page, it gives me this error: [Error-Image](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/hMMWLsvWozsQrDehIejGyibkF40AU4T8draWNBD6CqnTW0XaeW3GRbSn56ynyno4hyNKMvWcrwZZ_-gBH2JDamX5Rfr7g-gNYDOGH3rGG6osuBl1yRJM8pIsQqJUEFNW8LQT9q31LAwOiXK3dzZLTQI_Nj4qxxTCm0tMZYe0NOWqRsU9hjAMrF3-RXcn6ePgaDvNXal1CUizyPwi5AbCMpWZRVuJLDMziMwc-O7Ag5hZSI8eMh98AfCCje-qFOOuWerLLAxNSiBIKOe8IbILOqYqy7xRoyV7oPpwY6RIxO6FcIlzoDR6nqVtrpf5bAeB24bKpkKC5ArRH1jUzWU_0AwVqvixYVercZBI-LmipNx3PvtxLpwAOwlLBQEFG1yCwp1_P6e-JispSv4HOKPXcVvnG6vwxeMet-OpVOMv3tjbQYRZSvQg7IoNpj8wjyDn1ATCE4YEE1_4_4WJlF4foerehNTzrMIX1Pe2Wtl2TOT9plhOks_RHAXBE76EH2yUwB4XcqpykgPEfGJ68nsMLG3Xy5h8k6qxnzhYJSncyS_2nzrVRIG-GUoakhwVHaR4-vsNzhJ9mOiBvodWVWKI3rXKYFNcYfvuoGPVVc4=w1920-h841)

why this happens? and what should i do to fix it?

Comment: you need to new up the Url property somewhere, e.g. in a constructor. By default it will be null.

Comment: Can you please explain better or give an example. Sorry I am new to c#.

Comment: @hassan.ef's provided one below

Comment: The example below is not working

Comment: I don't think the problem is with the MVC or Razor parts as both can deal with Models that include Lists out of the box (I assume your Post entity is a Model?). It must be something in your scaffolding component?

Comment: Yes it is a model. So should I manualy create the razor pages?

Comment: You could do, it's certainly possible to iterate a List in a razor page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each product can have multiple images, you have a  one-to-many relationship and the image paths needs their own table. You should create an new class:

```
public FilePath
{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public string Path {get;set;}
}
```

Then the ImagePath property will look like this:

```
public List<FilePath> ImagePath {get;set;}
```

However, if each product only has one image, your property shouldn't be a collection:

```
public string ImagePath {get;set;}
```

Comment: Hassan thanks for answering but I still get the same error.

Comment: use this link:https://forums.asp.net/t/2096921.aspx?list+string+is+not+a+supported+primitive+type+or+a+valid+entity+type

Comment: Hassan, the answer over there is correct and now I can add a list of images. Thank you and could you please edit your answer acording to the link so I can then tick.

Comment: Muszeo, what do you mean by OP?

Comment: Saatvik, OP means Original Poster as in the question owner/creator.

Comment: Hassan, when i try to acess the image url from the razor page using: <img src="@item.Url[0].Path" class="d-block w-100" alt="@item.Text"> i get the error: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @ Saatvik debug your code and check object @item that is null or not null and also url property in that object is null or not null?